# How to make html list to be positioned against the side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a html list:

```
<div id="UInav">
    <ul id="UInavList">
        <li>My Activity</li>
        <li>My Tests</li>
        <li>Messaging</li>
        <li>Search</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get rid of the bullets and place it snug against the side of the page. How would I do this?

I added this CSS, but it only removed the bullets:

```
#UInavList {
             list-style-type: none;
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#UInavList,
#UInavList li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the default margin/padding on the ul.  I usually use a [css reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) of some sort to achieve this on all of my sites.  it will also include the list-style non on your UL

Answer (score 0):

```
#UInavList {
             list-style-type: none;
             margin-left:0px;
           }
```